# CAtlRegExp expression issue w/ begin/end anchors

Tags: c++, regex

I have some code that uses the CAtlRegExp to perform some validation. In the particular case, a zip-code (5 or 5-4 format). In addition, I want the data to be exactly that, so I'm using anchors (^ and $). When I use the anchor-less expression the Match call succeeds. When I add the anchors, the Match call fails with the exact same data.

The code below is what I'm doing, with the values supplied in code for the failing case. I'll admit to not being a regular expression wizard, but RegEx Buddy is happy w/ the format expression as it is in code.

Any help would be appreciated. And if I'm missing anything, please let me know.

Thanks.

```
sData = "12345-1234";
m_FormatExpression = "^(\\d{5})(-(\\d{4}))?$";

CAtlRegExp<>   regex;
REParseError   status = regex.Parse( m_FormatExpression );

if( REPARSE_ERROR_OK == status )
{
   CAtlREMatchContext<> match;
   if( regex.Match( sData, &match ) )
   {
      result = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Completely changed my answer when I figured out the problem.

The [CAtlRegExp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3zs4axe(v=vs.80).aspx) class does not support the repeat count in curly braces `{}`; it uses those for returning match objects.  The `5` and `4` in your expression were literal characters that it had to match. It's just a coincidence that the string you were testing with had a `5` in it, while the part with the `4` was optional. This expression works perfectly:

```
m_FormatExpression = "^\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d(-\\d\\d\\d\\d)?$";
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but alas, nothing. Add either anchor, and it fails to match. I've tried quite a few permutations, to no avail. What is interesting is "^.*$" will match anything.

Comment: @DevSolo, new and completely different answer. You're going to smack your forehead when you see it.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but after fighting all morning, I switched to Boost and it just worked, as it should. These are for custom validations and having to switch the regex to work w/ what appears to be a bug isn't acceptable. giving you credit for the answer though, as it is one.  thanks again.